# Is it possible to use a python script in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I observe that I cannot instantiate a child process in Vue.js. Is there any way to execute a python script in Vue.js (2.x) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vue is strictly a client-side framework, except when being used from Nuxt.js. If you're not using Nuxt, you would need a server of some sort (whether Python or Node or something else), and that could call a python script when needed. If you are using Nuxt, you could call Node's `child_process.spawn` (or exec, or spawnSync or execSync) to run a Python script (see [these docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/#custom-api-endpoint)). One last alternative would be transpiling your python to JS or compiling it to WebAssembly, but it sounds like what you want to do is run a server-side script, so that wouldn't work for you. My recommendation would be to serve your Vue app from a Python server (or some other server that can exec Python).

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can add pyscript, see: https://pyscript.net/